# Will installing a new kernel bork my secure boot windows partition?

Tags: dual-boot, secure-boot

I just installed Ubuntu alongside windows with secure boot enabled (I can't disabled it, this is a work laptop), and Windows detected some changes to the EFI partition and locked itself (i.e. bitlocker). I managed to get the recovery key and get it unlocked, but I'm wondering how sensitive it is to changes. If I install a new kernel, will that change the EFI partition and lead windows to lock up again?

Comment: When dual-booting with any Windows 8 or newer, disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. That's where you should start. With or without Secure Boot both OSes should boot fine irrespective of any updates (except with Windows feature updates that may change the boot order back to Windows but that's easily reversed in UEFI settings > Boot).

Comment: "locked itself" -- are you talking about bitlocker here?  PCR registers might change with shim/grub addition (that's why you need a recovery key and not rely on the default PCR registers), but adding a kernel shouldn't, since nothing changes on the EFI partition.

Comment: Yes bitlocker, should have specified. Question is updated

Answer (score 0):

Installing software in Ubuntu does not have any effect on the Windows OS in a dual boot computer, except if that software is related to the bootloader in which case it's possible that it could cause Windows to be unable to boot. Installing a new Linux kernel or upgrading the kernel in Ubuntu can sometimes cause Ubuntu to be unable to boot from that new kernel, but it would not have any effect on booting the Windows operating system in a dual boot. By default Ubuntu keeps the two latest installed kernels when you run `sudo apt autoremove`, so that if Ubuntu is unable to boot after upgrading the kernel you can still boot Ubuntu by selecting the other kernel.

Answer (score -1):

The answer can be very short and simple. No. Installing a new kernel would not be a problem.